# How do I customize the "Grabbing Hand" cursor?

Tags: windows-10, themes, mouse-cursor

I've been customizing my cursors in Windows 10, but I notice when I go to Control Panel>Mouse>Pointers, there's no option to customize the grabbing-hand icon that appears in PDF readers and web pages, which typically allows you to click and drag things to rearrange them.

Mozilla documents this cursor on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

How do I customize this cursor?

Comment: With a tampermonkey userscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have scoured the internet and windows settings to find nothing. I'm pretty sure its impossible without doing some coding or mods or something. I'd love it if someone would make a program for this or prove me wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but if someone comes across it, here is what you do: scroll over a page and when you see the Hand Tool, right click on the mouse until you find the pop up menu that will allow you to change it from "Hand Tool" to Pointer. Just double click on the other option (pointer) and it will change it automatically. Keep trying a few times because you may not see it right away...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is just an image or an icon. You can create a png file with the cursor you want. Then you can convert png to .cur file online. Paste cursor in any folder and select it or else paste in c:\Windows\Cursors folder.

Then navigate to Control panel -> Mouse -> pointers. Browse the file you added and select it.

Note : As I saw there is an animated cursor option with .ani extension. We can create such cursors as well. But I don't have much idea on it. And this may be a windows enterprise thing.

Comment: Where is "under pointers"? I've found no indication of where this icon is stored.

Comment: Navigate to Control panel -> Mouse -> Pointers. There is a browse button which can be used to upload a .cur file.

Comment: There's no grabbing hand icon there.

Comment: As I said, you need to create an image which you want, convert it to .cur and then place it into the directory and select it.

Comment: Select it under what category?  There is no "grabbing hand" category under Control Panel>Mouse>Pointers. If I were to add the grabbing hand cursor, it would be replacing some other mouse cursor icon, which is not what I want.  I want to replace the grabbing hand cursor.